# Files after copy via rsync-ssh all at least 1 MB in size

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync, ext4, size

After rsyncing an 200 MB directory mostly containing a few KB php files, the directory is now over 70 GB on the target machine.

The disk usage of every file is now at least 1 MB.

```
du -hxd1 /path/to/file.php
1.0M    /path/to/file.php
```

A ls tells me something different.

```
ls -lah /path/to/file.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 178 May 12 18:37 /path/to/file.php
```

Already checked block size. Source and target is ext4, block size both 4096.

I'm a bit confused.

Comment: When comparing to `ls`, you need `ls -hls` to actually tell if it's "something different".

Comment: "Source and target is ext4" – Local ext4 filesystems? Or is NFS or Samba involved?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `ls -sh`

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?